# Preventing scroll to top when a hash link is clicked w/ Jquery ScrollTo plugin

Tags: javascript, html, hash, scroll, position

This is driving me nuts! I have content mid page that would scroll not unlike a slide show, each icon represents a new section of content that would refresh in the view space.

My issue is every time a hash link is clicked it, the content does refresh but I am taken to the top of the page where the content is now out of view.

I've tried what I assumed would help:

```
return false
preventDefault
Dummy hashes ( #_XYZ)
#null
onClick="return false"
href="javascript;void(0);"
```

Nothing helped. I am assuming I need to grab and set page position but being a JS beginner I am not sure how to apply it correctly.

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
$('#case1Step1').click(function(e)
{
      e.preventDefault();
    $('#webMain').fadeOut('normal',function(e)
    {
        $('#step1Case1').fadeIn();
    });     
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'WebThumbs', 'big']);
    return false;
}
);
```

---

Again this response is working but I look page position and end up on top of page.

Comment: Calling e.preventDefault() should prevent the browser from navigating to the hash link. Does the hash link appear in the address bar after the link is clicked?

Comment: No it doesn't appear in the address bar so it works as should in that manor but the browser still responds to it and scrolls to top of page.

Comment: You might try calling it at the beginning of the click handler, or commenting out all of the other code in the click handler except for the e.preventDefault() call.

Comment: Just a paste error - I edited the code in the post to match exactly what I am using. Hash is NOT showing up in URL but scroll position is still returning to the top. it would seem that `e.preventDefault();` removes the hash for sure but does not prevent the browser response.

Comment: You can always replace your hash with a null JavaScript protocol: href="javascript://"

Comment: Yeah tried that too - still shift position to top.

Comment: Try to profile in FireBug, maybe other function is fired up meanwhile and do scroll top.